# Bootstrap Active Button Text Color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Sorry to bother you guys again... I've looked everywhere for the answer to this, but I still can't seem to figure it out.

I need to change the text color of the active button in Bootstrap. Basically when you click on one of the buttons it will go from being white to some sort of green color, and I want to change that color. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can do this?

I've tried this in CSS:

```
.button:focus, .button.active, .button.active:focus {
    color: white !important;
}
```

However, that didn't work.

(And can someone tell me how I can just put code in without the "run code" but it still colors it properly?)

Here's my code:

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/3.3.5/darkly/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/3.3.5/darkly/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<html lang="en">
    
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="dropdowns">
                <a class="navbar-brand" id="brand">Traders: </a>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">General <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-left" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#medical">Medical</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#utility">Utility</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#supplies">Supplies</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#banker">Banker</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">Vehicles <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-left" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#aircraft">Aircraft </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#vehicle">Vehicle </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                
                <li class="button"><a href="#blackmarket">Black Market</a></li>
                
                <li class="button"><a href="#wholesaler">Wholesaler</a></li>
                
                <li class="button"><a href="#hero">Hero</a></li>
                
                <li class="button"><a href="#bandit">Bandit</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <body></body>
    
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
@media {
    ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
        display: block;    
    }
    
    .navbar-custom {
        color: #262626;
        background-color: #262626;
    }
    
    .button:hover a{
        color: white !important;
    }
    
    .navbar-default {
        color: #262626;
        background-color: #262626;
        border-top: 4px solid red;
    }
    
    .navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover {
        color: white;
    }
     
    .dropdown:hover a{
        color: white !important;
    }
    
    .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
        background-color: #3d3d3d;
    }
    
}

body {
    background-color: black;
}

#navbar {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Are you attempting to override the `anchor tag` that is nested in your menu?

Comment: I'm trying to override the active button text color. When you click on a button it changes the font color, and I want that to stay white.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS has different pseudo selector by which you can achieve such effect. In your case you can use

`:active` : if you want background color only when the button is clicked and don't want to persist.

`:focus`: if you want background color untill the focus is on the button.

http://jsfiddle.net/zakCa/1017/

```
.button:focus
{
    font-size: 13px;
    color:orange;
}
```

Comment: I'm not trying to change the background color of the button itself, I'm trying to change the text color when the button is active. Color of the text when the button is active: https://sc-cdn.scaleengine.net/i/a17dfc13698b68721078957e94280f091.png

Comment: @Daedalus, updated the answer. Got a working example as well.

Comment: @Daedalus, from your code, I see that this works. The only case when it does not work, is when you have nested elemens or an ul or li elements. In this case, you should use the same logic (`color:orange`), but for `li` elements.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still very very new to HTML/CSS/Bootstrap, could you help me understand more what it is that I need to do?

Comment: The active button is changing his color as I can see. BUT, you have a dropdown menu item that needs to change the color. There, you won't change the color of the item, because the `li` item will be changed, since it's the item you click. To do this for `ul`, you simply add the color change for the `li` items. And when you click one, the `li` element will change his color.

Comment: How did you get it to work? I'm sorry for sounding like such a rookie.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. I added: .nav > li > a {color: white !important;} and that did it. Thanks!

Comment: @Daedalus, don't need to be sorry asking questions that give you a hard time. It's normal! And yes, li > a would sufice, but if that worked, it's good. The point is that you need to color a link item when you hover it. Therefore, you need to color an item, since you have a list marked as menu item.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which button you are attempting to restyle, you can override the property with a few lines of CSS. The following is some example code:

### HTML

```
<button class="btn-success btn">
  Change My Color
</button>
```

### CSS

```
.btn-success:active,
.btn-success.active {
  color: blue !important;
}
```

This works by overriding the default CSS that Bootstrap employs.

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kxphmgvm/1/)

Comment: I tried that, it didn't seem to work. I've updated the OP with all of my code.